# MySql select points contained in polygon

Tags: mysql-spatial

I am extremely new to mysql, but I cannot find the error in this query

```
SELECT latitude, longitude from mytable where ST_CONTAINS(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((47 -67, 47 -123, 21 -78, 47 -67)'), point(longitude, latitude))
```

The polygon is a triangle that covers most of the US. All of the lat/lng of the points should be inside the above polygon wkt, yet I get no rows. I have reversed the wkt coords in case I had it backwards, but still no luck. I am hoping I have an obvious mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You are missing a closing parentheses at the end:

SELECT latitude, longitude from mytable where ST_CONTAINS(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT('POLYGON((47 -67, 47 -123, 21 -78, 47 -67)'), point(longitude, latitude))**)**

Comment: Thank you. It was a closing parens, just a different one ('POLYGON((47 -67, 47 -123, 21 -78, 47 -67)**)**')